# Menu bar invisible in Emacs

Tags: icons, themes, emacs

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu, then installed Emacs. The icon bar (with commands such as copy and paste) is invisible (grey).

When launching Emacs in a terminal, I get this :

```
(emacs:15443): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-new' for stock: L'icône « document-new » n'est pas présente dans le thème Adwaita

(emacs:15443): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-open' for stock: L'icône « document-open » n'est pas présente dans le thème Adwaita

(emacs:15443): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'window-close' for stock: L'icône « window-close » n'est pas présente dans le thème Adwaita

(emacs:15443): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-save' for stock: L'icône « document-save » n'est pas présente dans le thème Adwaita

(emacs:15443): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-undo' for stock: 

(emacs:15443): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-cut' for stock: L'icône « edit-cut » n'est pas présente dans le thème Adwaita

(emacs:15443): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-copy' for stock: L'icône « edit-copy » n'est pas présente dans le thème Adwaita

(emacs:15443): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-paste' for stock: L'icône « edit-paste » n'est pas présente dans le thème Adwaita
```

The second part of the sentences means "the 'x' icon isn't in the Adwaita theme".

It seems like icons are missing from the theme. How can I get them ?

Comment: Could you please post the error message in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the full theme:

```
sudo apt-get install adwaita-icon-theme-full
```

The icons that you are receiving errors regarding are listed as present in [that package.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/adwaita-icon-theme-full/filelist)